# dialogContext.activeDialog is undefined during waterfall step

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to authenticate users using the following oAuth prompt:

```js
private oauthPrompt = new OAuthPrompt("sign-in", {
    connectionName: this.oauthSigninAzureId,
    title: "Login"
});
```

Then I create the waterfall steps:

```js
 private waterfall = new WaterfallDialog(INTENTS.GREETING, [
        (step: WaterfallStepContext) => {
            return step.prompt(
                INTENTS.SIGN_IN,
                " Hello and welcome."
            )
        }, async (step: WaterfallStepContext) => {
            const token = step.result.token;
            ...
        },
    ]);
```

Then I run it:

```js
const dialogContext = await this.dialogs.createContext(context); // activeDialog is ALWAYS empty
if (!dialogContext.activeDialog) await dialogContext.beginDialog("sign-in");
else dialogContext.continueDialog();
```

The first step runs fine. But then when trying to see if there is an active dialog, I check `dialogContext.activeDialog` only to find out it's undefined.

Comment: Can you share how you're checking dialogContext.activeDialog?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I edited my post to include it under "Then I run it:"

Comment: I'm still looking into ActiveDialog, but why aren't you using DialogTurnStatus instead?

Comment: I believe I didn't use it because I was following a tutorial in one of the documentations Microsoft provided. I can't remember at this point.

Comment: It turns out this was not working in the web chat sdk, but it was working in the bot emulator. I was authenticating the user the instant they entered the chat. So I immediately ran `dialogContext.continueDialog()` before running anything else, even before `dialogContext.beginDialog(...)` was ran, and now it works. I don't know why.